# How can I display topojson with three.js basic?

Tags: json, three.js, topojson

I would like to use an exisiting shapefile and extrude it with three.js

I have made a basic topojson file which I would like to extrude with three.js like this https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shape#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2

The shapefile is here... https://github.com/jamestknz/store/blob/master/house.geojson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've prepared a basic live demo that shows how to parse the JSON into instances of `THREE.Shape`. You can then use these shapes in order to create an instance of `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry`.

The idea is to iterate over all `feature` definitions and interprete each `geometry` definition as an instance of `THREE.Shape`. The code looks like so:

```
function parseGEOJSON( json ) {

    const features = json.features;
    const shapes = [];

    for ( const feature of features ) {

        const coordinates = feature.geometry.coordinates;

        for ( const coordinate of coordinates ) {

            // contour

            const points = [];

            const contour = coordinate[ 0 ];

            for ( const point of contour ) {

                points.push( new THREE.Vector2( point[ 0 ], point[ 1 ] ) );

            }

            const shape = new THREE.Shape( points );

            // hole

            const hole = coordinate[ 1 ];

            if ( hole ) {

                const path = new THREE.Path();

                for ( let i = 0; i < hole.length; i ++ ) {

                    const point = hole[ i ];

                    if ( i === 0 ) {

                        path.moveTo( point[ 0 ], point[ 1 ] );

                    } else {

                        path.lineTo(  point[ 0 ], point[ 1 ] );

                    }

                }

                shape.holes.push( path );

            }

            shapes.push( shape );

        }

    }

    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shapes, {
        depth: 0.1,
        bevelEnabled: false
    } );

    geometry.center();

    return geometry;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dqfnxcuk/

`three.js R108`

Comment: Thank-you, this is great :D